# How to change one value in an associative array referenced by Node

Tags: yaml

So I apologize in advance if I use yaml terminology wrong I am pretty new to it.

So I have this item in a list that is an associative array and I would like to use a node to repeat it multiple times in the file but I need to change one value in a sub array in it and I don't know how to do it without overwriting the entire array.

So here is the item in the list

`- &def_service
    type: service
    name: Remote Service
    config:
      machine: ''
      version: '1.0.0'
      apikey: VALUE_I_WANT_TO_CHANGE`

and I what I've tried to do is

`- <<: *def_service
    config:
      apikey: NEW_VALUE`

but that just overwrites the entire array so config is just

`{config:{apikey:NEW_VALUE}}`

I would be very grateful for an answer here I am pretty stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so an answer that occurred to me maybe not the best answer is just to introduce another variable for the config array like this.

`- &def_service
    type: service
    name: Remote Service
    config: &service_config
      machine: ''
      version: '1.0.0'
      apikey: VALUE_I_WANT_TO_CHANGE`

so to reference it I did this

`- <<: *def_service
    config:
      <<: *service_config
      apikey: NEW_VALUE`

Answer (score 0):

YAML is not a programming language. It is designed for data representation, not for data transformation.

The merge key you use (`<<`) is not part of the YAML specification. It is part of the YAML type repository, which is outdated (since it is defined for YAML 1.1). Therefore, your question is highly dependendent on the YAML processor you use. One processor might implement it while another does not.

Since you have a specific problem, it would probably be better to write YAML tailored to your problem, and then handle it in your code (assuming that you are in charge of the code). Something like this:

```
- !config_base
  &def_service
  type: service
  name: Remote Service
  config: &service_config
    machine: ''
    version: '1.0.0'
    apikey: VALUE_I_WANT_TO_CHANGE

- !config_child
  base: *def_service
  substitutions:
    config:
      apikey: NEW_VALUE
```

You can then write code that does the substitution inside your deserialized YAML structure.